# How to solve Flutter error with gradle 1151

Tags: flutter, gradle

After an upgrade of my flutter , i am having this issue on all my projects :

```
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/nunyalab/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1151
```

here are my gradle files

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
}
 }

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"   
}
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

and

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
```

def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 33
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.pikipikiafrica.pikirider"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

}

flutter {
source '../..'
}

dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.6.0')
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.+'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project using `flutter clean`?

Comment: yes i do, but still having the issue

Comment: May I know which IDE you are using?

Comment: i'm using android studio

Comment: Please share your gradle file

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, then I replaced thw `flutter build apk` command with the following to get the actual reason of the failure.

```
flutter build apk --debug --verbose
```

Then I got to know that I need to change **minSdkVersion** from 21 to 24.

[image]